# Open LDAP restrict access for user in group for artifactory

Tags: ldap, artifactory

I'm trying to connect artifactory (maven repository) to our open ldap.
I want to restrict access to users only in group 'developers'.
Sadly I'm far from being a ldap expert. That's the current problem here..
So if I don't do any filters on groups it's working.

Now I have setup a group developers, where the user 'adrian' is a uniqueMember of developers.

I hope my screenshots are a little help..[image: basic config without filter]

And here is the hierarchy:
[image]

And this is how the user 'adrian' is added to the group developers
[image]

So I tried already configuring the base path and filter like this:

```
search base: ou=group
filter: (uniqueMember=uid={0},ou=people,dc=firstbird,dc=eu)
```

I also left the search base completely blank..but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 2):

You should not mix "User DN pattern" and "Search Filter" but rather use one of them. In your case you should use a search filter since the "User DN pattern" is used for "direct" user authentication.
You can use the following search filters:

```
(uniqueMember=uid={0},ou=people,dc=firstbird,dc=eu)
```

or

```
(&(uid={0})(uniqueMember=uid={0},ou=people,dc=firstbird,dc=eu))
```

The search base should be `ou=people` (an empty one will also work)

Comment: hey I'll give that a try. Thanks! I'll come back as soon as I tested it :)

Comment: Hi, I just tried your search filter sadly that didn't work. Sadly the logs don't show much. I was not able to enhance the log level because the tutorials google showed me sometimes say something about editing a slapd.conf which I clearly don't have

Comment: You can set the log level of the following loggers to debug:   `org.artifactory.security.ldap`  
`org.springframework.ldap`  
`org.springframework.security.ldap`

Comment: thx, the other thing is that I don't see any log information within openldap